# Cannot Upsert only one value on struct interface from Mongo record [mgo]:golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Basically I want update in one value from the mongodb document by given **fully** struct interface as a change parameter in **collection.Upsert(selector,change)**. how we do this without lose other values into empty. Other(type,category.rerportby,createon,info) values should be keep on *existing values* only update *plant* and *location* values into *PLANT07* and *BAR*)

> **NOTE:** I want use **completely** Service Notification Struct Object for
>   do this.

```
DatabaseName:WO 
CollectionName:SERVICE_NOTIFICATIONS
```

package models

```
//models.ServiceNotification
type ServiceNotification struct {
    NotificationNo string                `json:"notification_no" bson:"notification_no"`
    Type           string                `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Category       string                `json:"category" bson:"category"`
        Plant          string                `json:"plant" bson:"plant"`
    Location         string              `json:"location" bson:"location"`
    ReportedBy     string                `json:"reportedby" bson:"reportedby"`
    Info           map[string]interface{}`json:"info" bson:"info"`
    SAPInfo        SAPNotificationInfo   `json:"sapinfo" bson:"sapinfo"`
        CreateOn       string                `json:"createon" bson:"createon"`
    UpdateOn       string                `json:"updateon" bson:"updateon"`
}

package main

func main(){

input := models.ServiceNotification{
    NotificationNo:000120,
    Plant:"Plant07",
    Location:"BAR",
}
Change_ServiceNotification(input)

}
```

> I want update plant and location by given complete struct interface to the mongo Upsert function. because I want to decide dynamically what should
>   update . But when I update plant and location other values going
>   to be **LOST**. in mongo record.

```
func Change_ServiceNotification(notification models.ServiceNotification) error {
    session, err := commons.GetMongoSession()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Cannot create mongodb session" + err.Error())
    }
    defer session.Close()
    var col = session.DB(WO).C(SERVICE_NOTIFICATIONS)

    selector := bson.M{"notification_no": notification.NotificationNo}

    _, err = col.Upsert(selector, notification)
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := "Cannot update service notification " + err.Error()
        return errors.New(errMsg)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Appreciate your help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it this way, but you can use the $set operator of MongoDB (Skipping error checking):

```
input := Bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "plant": "Plant07",
        // Further fields here...
    }
}
selector := bson.M{"notification_no": notification.NotificationNo}
col.Upsert(selector, input)
```

This will update only the provided fields.